# Problem with Scroll View inside a Layout Builder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-web

The problem is the following, I built my layout with a Layout Builder, inside it I check the screen size in width and define if it is a mobile device or a desktop/web, then I display the following layout >>>>

[image]

So far so good, but under the text 'a quiet afternoon' I want to put a list view with recommendations for songs to listen to in the afternoon, when I put the listview in the layout this happens here >>>>>

[image]

I don't know what's going on, so I'll put the whole code here, if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it!!

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:desktop_window/desktop_window.dart';
import 'package:player/sreens/Home.dart';
import 'package:player/sreens/MainScreen.dart';
import 'package:player/sreens/playlist.dart';
import 'package:player/sreens/search.dart';
import 'package:universal_platform/universal_platform.dart';

Future setDesktopWindow() async {
  await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(const Size(400, 400));
  await DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(const Size(1200, 700));
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (UniversalPlatform.isDesktop) {
    setDesktopWindow();
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Home(),
      '/main': (context) => MainScreen(),
      '/playlist': (context) => Playlist(),
      '/search': (context) => Search()
    },
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: "Music Player",
  ));
}
```

**Home.dart** (Inicial Route and Layout Builder is here!)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:player/sreens/MainScreen.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ///Item atual em exibição na tela e selecionado na barra de navegação
  ///Valor padrão 0.
  int _selectIndex = 0;

  ///Destination Rail, barra de navegação Lateral, Itens da barra de navegação
  final destinationRail = const <NavigationRailDestination>[
    NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text("Home")),
    NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_play), label: Text("Playlist")),
    NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: Text("Search")),
  ];

  ///Destination Bottom, barra de navegação inferior, Itens da barra de navegação
  final destinationBottom = const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_play),
      label: "Playlist",
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: "Search"),
  ];

  ///Método para trocar o item atual das barras de navegação
  changeDestination(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///Lista de telas a exibir em cada botão das barras de navegação.
    List<Widget> screens = [
      MainScreen(),
      Text("playlist"),
      Text("search"),
    ];

    ///Construção do layout principal, com as barras de navegação
    ///Utilizando o layout builder para definir qual barra demonstrar
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constrain) {
        if (constrain.maxWidth > 400) {
          ///Tamanho Desktop e Web
          return Scaffold(
            body: Row(
              children: [
                NavigationRail(
                  selectedIndex: _selectIndex,
                  destinations: destinationRail,
                  onDestinationSelected: changeDestination,
                  labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    width: 1,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      screens[_selectIndex]
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          ///Tamanho Mobile
          return Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              items: destinationBottom,
              currentIndex: _selectIndex,
              onTap: (indicie) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectIndex = indicie;
                });
              },
            ),
            body: screens[_selectIndex],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**MainScreen.dart** (the listview is here)

```
import '../utils/timeValidator.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                timeValidator(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontFamily: 'nunito',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.nightlight_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Image.asset(
                imageValidator(),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 300,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            sugestionValidator(),
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'nunito',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 20),
          ),
************This is the error*************
          ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Teste"),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: 4)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here `ListTile` is trying to get infinite width while the `ListView` is on `horizontal` axis, this also providing infinite width. You can provide width on `ListTile` to fix this issue.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded( //or SizedBo with Height instead shrinkWrap for better perfomance
              child: ListView.separated(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text("Teste"),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                  itemCount: 4),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to fix the problem and here's the thing, I had to use a **CustomScrollView** to be able to create the layout perfectly and without errors, using **Slivers** and **Containers** as parent components so I was able to create what I wanted, thanks